# WebApi2 app returns 403 Access denied error when referencing another WebApi2 app

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, reference, azure-web-app-service

I have a production app, running in azure, based on MVC, WebApi2, with attribute routing as the default routing mechanism. It includes a variety of useful classes for my new project, so I'd like to reference it's project in a new WebApi2 app. As soon as I do this, Owin cannot find a startup class. Once I define the new app as the default app with

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(NewApp.Startup))]
```

I only get a 403 response in whatever call to the new app. If I remove the old app from references, the new app loads normally. Anyone have any idea why that would be?

Comment: could you explain more detail about how to referencing another WebApi? Add REST API client?

Comment: Both the old Project and the new one are part of the same Solution. I simply add the old project as a reference to the new one.